# Embed Flex app into Mediawiki

Tags: apache-flex, mediawiki

I have a flex app, which I want to embed into a Mediawiki, preferably. in the form of an extension. Can anybody give some links or tell me, how to start.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Flash_Extension
?